# Azure Entity function "never" returns

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

The following code enters `GetIds` method and never return.

```
public static class ANameOrchestrator
{
    [FunctionName(CommonNames.AName)]
    public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(Documents), CommonNames.DocFlowFifo);
        var px = context.CreateEntityProxy<IDocuments>(entityId);
        IEnumerable<int> list = await px.GetIds();//never return or throw
    }
}
```

I tried to wrap the method call with `LockAsync` in which case the execution deadlocked on the call.

```
public static class ANameInOrchestrator
{
    [FunctionName(CommonNames.AName)]
    public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {

        IEnumerable<int> list;
        var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(Documents), CommonNames.DocFlowFifo);
        using (var lk = await context.LockAsync(entityId)) //never goes beyond the call to LockAync
        {
            var x = context.CreateEntityProxy<IDocuments>(entityId);
            list = await x.GetIds();
        }
     }          
 }
```

How to resolve the problem? What direction do I have to look?
**Edit**
using alternative version to call the entity operation doesn't work either

```
list = await context.CallEntityAsync<IEnumerable<int>>(entityId, nameof(Documents.GetIds));
```

Comment: The problem resolution comes from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator clear all